# WxWidgets - open new frame from button click

Tags: dialog, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm using CodeBlocks as IDE with WxWidgets in order to develop a simple application based on buttons actions: the user can click on different buttons to get information from the system. 
I would like to open a new frame when a button is clicked, but I do not know how to do it since I'm still a newby and I couldn't find any tutorial about this topic.
How can I create and launch a new frame when **Button1** is clicked?

If you can't help me, can you at least give me some good link where I can understand how to do this, please? 
How can I create and launch a new frame when **Button1** is clicked?

Thank you for your support!

This is my basic code:
**isolaApp.cpp**

```
    #include "isolaApp.h"

//(*AppHeaders
#include "isolaMain.h"
#include <wx/image.h>
//*)

IMPLEMENT_APP(isolaApp);

bool isolaApp::OnInit()
{

    bool wxsOK = true;
    wxInitAllImageHandlers();
    if ( wxsOK )
    {
        isolaFrame* Frame = new isolaFrame(1);
        Frame->Show();
        SetTopWindow(Frame);
    }

    return wxsOK;

}
```

**isolaMain.cpp**

```
#include "isolaMain.h"
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>

//(*InternalHeaders(isolaFrame)
#include <wx/intl.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
//*)

//helper functions
enum wxbuildinfoformat {
    short_f, long_f };

wxString wxbuildinfo(wxbuildinfoformat format)
{
    wxString wxbuild(wxVERSION_STRING);

    if (format == long_f )
    {
#if defined(__WXMSW__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Windows");
#elif defined(__UNIX__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Linux");
#endif

#if wxUSE_UNICODE
        wxbuild << _T("-Unicode build");
#else
        wxbuild << _T("-ANSI build");
#endif // wxUSE_UNICODE
    }

    return wxbuild;
}

//(*IdInit(isolaFrame)
const long isolaFrame::ID_BUTTON1 = wxNewId();
const long isolaFrame::ID_BUTTON2 = wxNewId();
const long isolaFrame::ID_SASHWINDOW1 = wxNewId();
const long isolaFrame::idMenuQuit = wxNewId();
const long isolaFrame::idMenuAbout = wxNewId();
const long isolaFrame::ID_STATUSBAR1 = wxNewId();
//*)

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(isolaFrame,wxFrame)
    //(*EventTable(isolaFrame)
    //*)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

isolaFrame::isolaFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
    //(*Initialize(isolaFrame)
    wxMenu* Menu1;
    wxMenu* Menu2;
    wxMenuBar* MenuBar1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem2;

    Create(parent, id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, _T("id"));
    SashWindow1 = new wxSashWindow(this, ID_SASHWINDOW1, wxPoint(168,72), wxDefaultSize, wxSW_3D|wxCLIP_CHILDREN, _T("ID_SASHWINDOW1"));
    Button1 = new wxButton(SashWindow1, ID_BUTTON1, _("Label"), wxPoint(143,163), wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
    Button2 = new wxButton(SashWindow1, ID_BUTTON2, _("Label"), wxPoint(143,225), wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON2"));
    SashWindow1->SetSashVisible(wxSASH_TOP,    true);
    SashWindow1->SetSashVisible(wxSASH_BOTTOM, true);
    SashWindow1->SetSashVisible(wxSASH_LEFT,   true);
    SashWindow1->SetSashVisible(wxSASH_RIGHT,  true);
    MenuBar1 = new wxMenuBar();
    Menu1 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem1 = new wxMenuItem(Menu1, idMenuQuit, _("Quit\tAlt-F4"), _("Quit the application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu1->Append(MenuItem1);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu1, _("&File"));
    Menu2 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem2 = new wxMenuItem(Menu2, idMenuAbout, _("About\tF1"), _("Show info about this application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu2->Append(MenuItem2);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu2, _("Help"));
    SetMenuBar(MenuBar1);
    StatusBar1 = new wxStatusBar(this, ID_STATUSBAR1, 0, _T("ID_STATUSBAR1"));
    int __wxStatusBarWidths_1[1] = { -1 };
    int __wxStatusBarStyles_1[1] = { wxSB_NORMAL };
    StatusBar1->SetFieldsCount(1,__wxStatusBarWidths_1);
    StatusBar1->SetStatusStyles(1,__wxStatusBarStyles_1);
    SetStatusBar(StatusBar1);

    Connect(ID_BUTTON1,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&isolaFrame::OnButton1Click);
    Connect(idMenuQuit,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&isolaFrame::OnQuit);
    Connect(idMenuAbout,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&isolaFrame::OnAbout);
    //*)
}

isolaFrame::~isolaFrame()
{
    //(*Destroy(isolaFrame)
    //*)
}

void isolaFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close();
}

void isolaFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxString msg = wxbuildinfo(long_f);
    wxMessageBox(msg, _("Welcome to..."));
}

void isolaFrame::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    // I want to show a new 
}
```

Comment: Looks like your identical post to the [wxW forum](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=46160) is producing the answers that you need (and more). This question here can probably be deleted.

Comment: Yes I'm going to close it

Answer (score 0):

To show a new frame, you just need to create it and then `Show()` it: the last step is important, as new frames are created initially hidden, so if you forget to call `Show()`, the frame will exist but neither you nor the users of your application will see it.